# Arrow on pure CSS menu drop down that has children

Tags: css

I have a pure CSS drop down menu that is working great but I want to have a drop down arrow on the parent menu items that have children to show the user the menu has choices/options.  I have this currently:

```
/* drop down arror */   
nav ul li > a:last-child:after  { content: ' ▾'; }
```

This puts a drop down arrow next to EVERY menu item EXCEPT the ones with children.  So what I need is an exact opposite to this. I wish there was an `a:has-child` or `a:is-parent`.  Any one know how to do this without going the JavaScript route or image route?

Thanks in advance for your help to my question

Comment: without the markup it was impossible to find a precise solution to your answer.

Comment: Check into less as it contains those requirements where variable css thrives. Sass could work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gosh, I was able to solve this just now using trial and error using the following code:

```
nav ul li > a:not(:last-child):after  { content: ' ▾'; }
```

The thing about it is I had tried this originally and it didn't work.

```
nav ul li > a:not:last-child:after  { content: ' ▾'; }
```

So the key is you have to use the parenthesis with the :not modifier which I was not aware.  Basically the not operator did the "opposite" of what I had and poof it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have a selection similar to what you want, it's just reversed. Try putting that arrow on every single item and then using the selector you created to hide it on those items it shouldn't show. The arrow will be left over on the items you couldn't select.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no method available at the moment to select the parent element via CSS.
If there was a way to do it, it would have been visible in the CSS selector specs:

[CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

I'd say that your options are to either asign different classes to the `ul`, e.g `<ul class="parent">` and `<ul class="sub-menu">` so you can select them in CSS, or target the parent elements via `javascript`